# Hough Transform Implementation and Edge Linking

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I think I understand the basics of the Hough transform.  I'm going to first summarize my understanding which will get to my question.  Each point in the edge image gets mapped to a sinusoidal in the theta-rho space.  Points on a line in the edge image have corresponding sinusoidal curves that intersect.  The goal is to find points with a large number of intersections because then we found the lines.

So the idea is that for each foreground pixel in the edge image, solve for its sinusoidal curve and plot it over an "accumulation" image, where we increment pixel values that the curve intersects.  Pixels in the accumulation image with high values correspond to large amounts of intersections, which would imply a line was found.

My question has to do with the step "plot it over an "accumulation" image".  Is this correct?  Are we essentially rasterizing the sinusoidal curve over the accumulation image?  Or am I misunderstanding this.

Second question.  How does this help with edge linking?  It tells us the lines, but how would I use this to fill in the gaps of "incomplete line segments" from edge detection?  Do I have to find all pixels near a line found from Hough transform, and then look at the gap size and decide if I want to bridge it or not?

Comment: You've got the general idea correct. It's not "plotted" in the accumulator space, but you can view the accumulator space plotted if you like. It's just points and you look for local peaks in the space. Also where have you heard of a Hough transform being used for edge linking? And what does edge linking mean in this context? You mean for a polygon or something?

Answer (score 2):

> plot it over an "accumulation" image

That's an awkward word choice, but more or less right. As you say, you rasterize the sinusoid and add 1 to each bin it falls on.

*Edge linking* is often applied as a second step. So in your Hough image you find peaks. Each peak represents a line across the image. You can visit the pixels along that line, find the ones that are set (assuming a binary input image). You will find sequences of set (foreground) pixels, each sequence has a certain length, and there is a distance between the end of one sequence and the start of the next (sequences of background pixels). Here you can fill in short sequences of background, or remove short sequences of foreground, or both (the order matters, of course). Filling in these background sequences is called *edge linking*.

Comment: Cris, do you know of a good example of this, with figures ideally, possibly with Matlab or Python code?

Comment: @MyCarta Matteo, the MATLAB `houghlines` does this. You set parameters 'FillGap' and 'MinLength'. If fills gaps first, then removes short segments.